# What is the best way to pass props to a ReactJS app before server side rendering happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am relatively new to ReactJS, and after one week of tests I decided to create a simple react app. The problem that I am facing is how to pass my database's data to the app. What is the best way to pass data to the app? Should I write data in json format or I need to make an ajax client-side call?

Comment: You can do both. But better to write it to the page as global variable and pass into app as prop.

Comment: Yes but my problem is that i've declared all the page in a component that is rendered server side. How can i pass the data throught the main component?

Comment: SSR is an advanced React topic. You can get away with AJAX just fine without it. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount